# How to ensure repeatability and reproducibility in a clinical study?

Tags: clinical-trials, reproducible-research

I have a 2 arm clinical study with topical anesthetic study group and placebo on the two arms. I measured the pain scores of patients with a pain scale. It is not an experimental study.In the method section, I explained sample size estimation, inclusion and exclusion criteria, randomization, pain assessment, blinding and statistics in great detail and  I made the study data available upon request. However, reviewer asked me " How to ensure repeatability and reproducibility of the findings" How can I solve this issue and what can I say to the reviewer?